# groupby list of lists of indexes

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a list of np. arrays, representing indexes of pandas dataframe.

I need to groupby index to get each group for each array

let's say, that is the df:

```
index values
0     2
1     3
2     2
3     2
4     4
5     4
6     1
7     4
8     4
9     4
```

and that is the list of np.arrays:

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([6, 7, 8])]
```

from this data I expect to get 2 groups without loop opertaions as a single groupby object:

group1:

```
index values
0     2
1     3
2     2
3     2
```

group2:

```
index values
6     1
7     4
8     4
```

I would stress again that finally I need to get a single groupby object.

Thank you!

Comment: why you do not want for loop ?

Comment: @peterWeNYoBen, it's millions of rows

Comment: But what about the list? is it only a few groups you'll cut down to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame([2,3,2,2,4,4,1,4,4,4],columns=['values'])
df.index.name ='index'
l=[np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]), np.array([6, 7, 8])]

group1= df.loc[pd.Series(l[0])]
group2= df.loc[pd.Series(l[1])]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have realized, that, my question was how to get a groupby object, like df.groupby('foo') to make vectorized calculations on, instead of a list of groups. Looking forward.

Comment: I separated the 2 groups

Answer (score 3):

I still using for-loop to create the `groupby` key `dict`

```
l=[np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]), np.array([6, 7, 8])]
df=pd.DataFrame([2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4],columns=['values'])

from collections import ChainMap
L=dict(ChainMap(*[dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x, y in enumerate(l)]))
list(df.groupby(L))
Out[33]: 
[(0.0,        values
  index        
  0           2
  1           3
  2           2
  3           2), (1.0,        values
  index        
  6           1
  7           4
  8           4)]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need a groupby object, like df.groupby('foo') to make vectorized calculations on, instead of a list of groups.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377):

```
l = [np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([6,7,8])]
df_indx = pd.DataFrame(l).stack().reset_index()
df_new = df.assign(foo=df['index'].map(df_indx.set_index(0)['level_0']))
for n,g in df_new.groupby('foo'):
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
   index  values  foo
0      0       2  0.0
1      1       3  0.0
2      2       2  0.0
3      3       2  0.0
   index  values  foo
6      6       1  1.0
7      7       4  1.0
8      8       4  1.0
```